# Regex conditional positive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm playing around with regular expressions at the moment trying to grasp them better and have a scenario with which I seem to struggle right now since I don't know whether that is even achievable through regex or not.

I have strings of text something like this

```
$array['key']['FirstWord']
$array['key']['FirstWord SecondWord']
$array['key']['FirstWord SecondWord ThirdWord']
$array['key']['FirstWord SecondWord ThirdWord FourthWord']
```

The list could be ongoing. I want to match (select) the whitespaces between the inner key words. So in second line it would be the whitespace between `FirstWord` and `SecondWord`.

With `^\$array\['key'\]\['(?:\w+ +)+` I'm able to match the lines that contain more than one word within the key. Putting the first part `(?<=^\$array\['key'\]\[')` as positive lookahead I'm able to put the "marker" Just before the key words would start and then I'm lost. I was thinking of using word boundaries and then select anything between them, but with no success so far. Any suggestions or pointers?

EDIT:
The assumption would be that there would be some other text between these lines also, so simple `\b`would not work as a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If supported, you could make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match.

You match either `^\$array\['key'\]\['` or you match 1 more word characters and forget what is currently matched using `\K`

Then match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars.

```
(?:^\$array\['key'\]\['(?=.*?'])\w+|\G(?!^))\w+\K\h+
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^\$array\['key'\]\['` Match `$array['key']['`
  - `(?=.*?'])` Positive lookahead, assert `']` on the right
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match (forget what was matched)
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQ7xiI/1)

Comment: Nice, +. Would you mind explaining the different parts? First time I see `\G` and `K` etc.

Comment: Sure, I am at lunch now but in a few mins I will add it.

Comment: So after I've played around with it a bit, as I understand `\G` sets anchor after every single character after the previous match and then from those you match for the word followed by whitespace. How so?

Comment: Any alternative suggestions if `\G` is not supported?

Comment: @NulisDefo There are other options, for example if a lookbehind is supported with an [infinite width pattern](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) you might use `(?<=^\$array\['.*) (?=.*?\])` https://regex101.com/r/vcA169/1 but this match is a bit broader.

Comment: In the last example (the more restrictive one) what is the purpose of `(?:\['\w+(?: \w+)*'\])*` part? The part after that seems to be achieving same thing. If you remove the later part of lookebehind, the earlier achieves nothing.

Comment: @NulisDefo You are right, the patten could be written as `(?<=^\$array\['key']\['\w+(?: \w+)*) (?=.*?'])` https://regex101.com/r/qw8RG1/1 I will remove the previous comment. This part `\w+(?: \w+)*` is to get to all the spaces the you want to match. If you omit `(?: \w+)*` then only the first space will be matched.